# Design of new functionality for existing control

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, decorator

guys,

I need advice... I would like to implement 'add new items' to grid view and 'remove selected items' from the same grid, like Add(IEnumerable newItems).

I would not like to implement derived grid view class, because I look for flexible solution without strong relation to grid.

I was investigating using of 'Decorator' pattern in my case, but I could not design it: decorator can contain/aggregate grid view (it is not problem), but decorator and grid view do not have common interface - i.e. 'add new items' is new functionality and grid view does not have it.
I could implement empty 'Add' method in grid view and wrap it in decorator (as alternative way).

Anyways, I will be glad any idea to design nice solution :)

Comment: I like it :) I am trying to implement this now

Comment: Just added a small answer. Tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [visitor pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx) seems to be a good fit for your problem.

> It represents an operation to be performed on the elements of an object
>   structure. Visitor lets you define a new operation without changing
>   the classes of the elements on which it operates.

Answer (score 0):

I think simplest way is extension methods:

```
public static class GridViewExtensions
{
   public static void RemoveSelectedItems(this GridView grid)
   {
      // implementation goes here
   }

   public static void Add<T>(this GridView grid, IEnumerable<T> items)
   {
      // implementation goes here
   }
}
```

Usage even simpler, than with decorated GridView - you don't need to create decorators, just use ordinal GridView:

```
gridView.RemoveSelectedItems();
```

With Decorator you must implement all public interface of decorated object and transfer calls to it. This is a lot of work for GridView.

UPDATE: Another solution - simply inherit from GridView and add your methods to derived class. Use your CustomGridView instead of GridView.

Comment: Yes, it is simplest... but I need store state that is dependent on new functionality.. in this case, extension does not help me.

Comment: State for adding and removing items?

Comment: Sorry, I do not explain point above. I do not afraid work :) Really, I want to design nice solution... I think I am not first who should implement similar issue.